# When I set my background-size to anything other than cover the text inside my div overfllows whenever the image resizes. How do I prevent that?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my background image to be responsive so changed the size to 100% and auto but now the texts that I have inside my section is overflowing out of the image. This wouldn't happen if my image size was cover. How do prevent the text to overflow from the image.

```
.section1{
    height: 600px;
    background: url("img/Rectangle 1.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;

}
```

html

```
<section class="section1">
        <div class="container info">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 " align="center">
              Make Future Visible <span>&trade;</span>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 info2" align="center">
              Real-time predictive analytics for refining equipment eliminate accidents<br>
              and fires, increases refinery uptime, decreases downtime and drastically<br>
              reduces maintenance costs.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the background position css to `top center` it will make the rectangle image start from the top of `<section>` element.

If you want the image 100% width, centred, and responsive, then a rectangle image will not work on a mobile.

See demo here https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/tfesu0cx/1/

Comment: Do you know how to prevent it from overflowing from the bottom?

Comment: Are you able to make the jsfiddle show your problem exactly. Can you change the image url in fiddle to use your image so I can see the problem?

Comment: Not sure if you can see it on your end but I made the live window smaller and whenever it's less than 298px the texts overflows from the bottom  https://jsfiddle.net/tfesu0cx/2/

Comment: If the image has stay proportionate. Then yes your text will overflow because your image is a rectangle and set to 100% width. You could use media query to set the background-size to cover when on a mobile. See example... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/tfesu0cx/4/ . Somehow i think this is still not guna solve your problem lol. It's hard to know what you need i'm sure I could fix it.